# Tactical Downvoting -was: Downvoting Answers by competing Answerers?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

EDIT as suggested:

I have noticed a not frequent (but present pattern) I would like to point out to the community.

An user that has a low reputation (usually <16), asks a question.

"Answerer1" user gives a good suggestion (Well documented, without grammatical mistakes, furnishes links, focus on the OP problem, and any comment contradict with logic what he or her is saying).

"Answerer2" user  gives **after "Answerer1"** a less good suggestion, based on (more o less) objective parameters, and downvote "Answerer1" to appear as a better suggestion.

Why I suppose "Answerer2" downvoted "Answerer1" if is not possible to know who downvoted a post?
For 3 reasons:

1) The quality of "Answerer1" is good.

2) The downvote and the reply of "Answerer2" are almost happening on the same time.

3) OP has a low reputation, is reasonably to assume could be influenced by a downvote, when will decide the right answer.

Comment: Look up 'SCITE'.

Comment: thanks looks this SCITE problem is not solved.Of course the cheater could log with another profile and then reply with another one( in the case would be possible to see who downvoted).It looks to me as a tricky grey area. A solution could be maybe to notify the reply to a senior that could win some reputation,badge points? After all sometimes the downvote is really evident to spot out as fake if one see the quality of the two answers.A  more general downvote detective badge feature could be a nice way to go.

Comment: There's not much that can be done about lack of fair play and tactical dving.

Comment: Don’t assume somebody commenting downvotes you.

Comment: sir possibly there is a misunderstanding, I am not assuming, nor explicitly  speaking over a personal case, but  inferring over a possibility ( that looks it exists from the comments), and I am proposing a solution for the community

Comment: I don't think this is an actual, real-life issue.

Comment: @trocchietto Instead of inferring something, take the downvote has an indication you should improve your answer, instead of assuming the author of another answer went to the effort to downvote an existing answer

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks you for your feedback, I understand your point.

Comment: As suggested, post has been edited on the basis of the suggestions under the original post

Comment: [SCITE reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19535#19535).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's actually a few things in place that kinda are meant to mitigate that.

*Firstly*, the reputation increase for an upvote is +10 (so 5 downvotes = one upvote), and while you lose 2 reputation for being downvoted, the downvoter loses 1.

Presumably people will read the answers and vote accordingly so your one 'tactical' downvote would also be mitigated by many many upvotes. After a while, anyway, you realise your answers can stand by themselves, and you don't need to sweat the haters.

So, eh, the system does actually take these things into account. While tactical downvoting isn't fair play (and I have at least once not gotten a bounty because someone tactically downvoted me past the +2 I needed to auto-get half of it), it's not that much of an issue, and most sites are not that insanely competitive.

Comment: possibly downvote could be considered to be rated -3 or -4 then from the person that votes. I think that downvote is a really important aspect.( Not to mention really good questions that get downvoted sometimes). But i see your point

Comment: and sorry you did not get the bounty.

Comment: @trocchietto Lots of bad questions get upvotes I don’t see anyone complaining about that.  If a question is getting multiple downvotes it means multiple people believe there is a quality problem with the question.

Comment: your logic is cristally clear Ramhound, I repeat, I see your point. There are also psychological factors to consider. Is not an easy subject. To me strictly referring to tactical down votes could be good -3 or -4, but about the consequences of that on general down votes I think there is much more to say.Just as example: to refer to @Journeyman Geek, we should consider that there are a lot of posts that get really few views, so the an upvote adjustment of an initial downvote is not always "regulated" by the environment. Too many variables involved